# Ionic Cordova InAppBrowser inside ion-content

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I need to load an external URL inside my app, made with Ionic 3.13.2 and Cordova 7.1.0 , and I'm using InAppBrowser plugin (due to render issues in ios, i cannot use iframe, object, or similar).
The problem is that when I load open the InAppBrowser, since it is a new window, I lose my tab bar at the bottoms so I lose the navigation capacity.
I wonder if it is possible to 'embed' an InAppbrowser inside ion-content.
So far I'm *tricking* it, loading the content and then injecting HTML simulating the tab bar, but it would be great if I would avoid this.

**Current behavior**

[image: current-behavior]

**Desired behavior**

[image: desired-behavior]

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution?

Comment: you can't ..as `inAppBrowser` is like a new window.. its similar to `window.open()` function. as soon as it open with the given URL previous window will be hide, so cant access/see the previous screen contents till you close it.

Comment: Anyone found solution so far. I am searching for a same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Plugin „themeablebrowser“
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Comment: Can you please let me know how can we get this result using themeablebrowser?